# Why does Qt implement QFile::size() which returns a qint64 rather than quint64

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qiodevice

So going through the [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) docs, I found [QFile::size()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#size) returns a [qint64](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qint64-typedef).

It would make sense (to me atleast) if [QFile::size()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#size) returned an unsigned integer i.e. [quint64](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#quint64-typedef) as file sizes range from 0 bytes and upwards. `QFile::size()` reimplements some methods from parent classes, i.e. [QFileDevice::size()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#size) and it again from [QIODevice::size()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#size). In non of these implementations any mention is made of negative numbers i.e. -1, etc.

The base implementation in [QIODevice::size()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#size) has a **description**:

> For open random-access devices, this function returns the size of the
> device. For open sequential devices, [bytesAvailable()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesAvailable) is returned.
>
> If the device is closed, the size returned will not reflect the actual
> size of the device.

In [QIODevice::bytesAvailable()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesAvailable) which dictates the return type of `QIODevice::size()` also makes no mention of -1 return values, however its return type is also `qint64`.

Is this an design decision for Qt that has a use for negative numbers if file sizes, and be extension their parent class(es) too i.e.

Comment: Maybe negative numbers are returned when the device is closed, and a similar thing is done for files?

Comment: @cigien looking through the docs, I didn't find any mention of it hence my interest in the data type

Comment: its a long-standing debate whether container sizes should be unsinged or not. There are a couple of nasty subtle errors, eg `for (unsigned i = 0; i < c.size()-1;++i)` with an empty container, that can be avoided with a signed size

Comment: Not sure about qt, but returning unsigned from `size` is a historical accident and a source of bugs. In fact, c++20 adds `ssize()` to solve this exact issue, so maybe that's what qt is going for.

Comment: FWIW, I'm in the camp that says size functions return signed integers.  That way you don't have to worry about unsigned arithmetic.  If you subtract to file sizes, and the first happens to be bigger then the second then instead of getting a negative number you get a very large number instead.

Comment: Qt in general uses signed ints everywhere.

Comment: consider that banning unsigned altogether is also a way to go (not a nice one, but others disagree), I think eventually it is purely opinion-based